# How does Dart run asynchronous code without blocking?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

How does Dart run asynchronous code without blocking?
For example:

```
void test(User user) async {
    print('test');

    String fullName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

    final result = await sendRequest(fullName);

    print('${result}');
}
```

I understand that when Dart runs async function, it executes code before await and then wraps the remaining code into Future and puts it into Event Loop. But, how does that Future what we're awaiting for (`await sendRequest(fullName)`) not blocking running the other, synchronous code? We should wait for request for complete but it also requires some code to check that we've received or not received response. How does it not block other operations, like button clicks?

Comment: I will recommend reading the following article: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function returns at the first `await`. It returns a future which will later be completed (which is then ignored because of the `void` return type). Everything else in the function happens in reaction to callbacks from other futures (or streams, if you use `await for`).

The `async` function here is basically rewritten into something like:

```dart
void test(User user) {
  print('test');
  String fullName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
  return sendRequest(fullName).then((final result) { // <-- Returns here, synchronously.
    print('${result}');    // <-- Gets called by the future of `sendRequst(fullName)`.
  });
}
```

This transformation is similar to a [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) transformation in the it takes the continuation (the control flow in the body of the function after the `await`) and makes it into a function.

(In reality, the transformation is more complicated because it needs to account for loops, `try`/`catch`/`finally`, and even `break` statements. Because of that, even a simple example like this one will likely be converted into something more complicated than absolutely necessary).

Comment: @Irn Thank you for your answer. I just want to clarify that I understand it correct. So, under the hood it works this way: adds future we're awaiting to the Event Loop, then just transforms await to .then() and creates a separate function of what goes after await keyword. And this function is added to the Event Loop when future we're awaiting for (await sendRequest() in this case) is done, right?

Comment: The function is added to the future that you are awaiting, to get called when that future completes. When that is depends entirely on what the code behind that future is doing. When the future completes, then the callback is run - possibly on the event loop, possibly just directly by the future. Again, depends entirely on the future, the good thing is that you don't need to care about that, the `Future` class abstracts over how and when the computation completes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification